# Swift / Camera error com.apple.tccd sandbox extension

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview

Since IOS 14.3 WkWebView supports Camera access but when i grant the permission it starts the camera but freezes on first frame. xCode gives me this in debug i'm new to this and don't really no what i means i've tried to load others sites with working examples with out luck. Also tried Google so it must be something with this "'com.apple.tccd' sandbox extension". I've already allowed camera and audio in info.plist which allowed me to "start" camera but then i freezes at first frame.

```
 Could not create a 'com.apple.tccd' sandbox extension

 [WebRTC] Unable to create com.apple.tccd sandbox extension
```

Comment: Hello Line, did you find a solution? Or have any additional comments? Currently similar troubles myself.

Comment: Is it working in Mac catalyst ? , In Mac catalyst it is not asking permission , If you know please help

Answer (score 0):

Having a similar issue with an audio-only setup. Building with XCode 12.5.1 *(instead of XCode 13)* makes it work for me *(I'm testing both side-by-side)*. However, it still outputs the error. Hope this works for you, too, in the meantime, until we find a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

Having the exact same issue when building with Xcode 13.
I noticed that the issue does not occur when the html file is loaded over https but only when it is a local file (a file that is included in the bundle)

Comment: It seems to be a bug of Fairplay since iOS 15. Should be fixed with iOS 15.1...